# How Can I integrate Python Turtle into Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle



def RunTurtle():
    import turtle

    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("light green")
    window.title("Turtle")
    t = turtle.Turtle()

    t.speed(20)

    def MyTurtleFunc(Fl, Sl, f, rin, ro, c, w):
        t.color(c)
        t.width(w)
        for _ in range(Fl):
            for _ in range(Sl):
                t.forward(f)
                t.right(rin)
            t.right(ro)

    MyTurtleFunc(36, 4, 100, 90, 10, "blue", 4)

def RunGUI():
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Project")
    canvas = Canvas(master, height=1080, width=1920)
    canvas.pack()

    def RUN():
        RunTurle()

    TopFrame = Frame(master, bg='light green')
    TopFrame.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.04, relwidth=0.91, relheight=0.6)

    MiddleFrame = Frame(master, bg='light blue')
    MiddleFrame.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.66, relwidth=0.91, relheight=0.06)

    BottomFrame = Frame(master, bg='orange')
    BottomFrame.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.74, relwidth=0.91, relheight=0.25)

    TopLabel = Label(TopFrame, bg='light green', text="Drawing Robot", font="calibri 15 bold", foreground="black")
    TopLabel.pack(padx=5, pady=5)



    LabelBottom = Label(BottomFrame, bg='orange', text="Debug Area ", font="vendara 15 bold ", foreground="black")
    LabelBottom.pack(padx=0.1, pady=0.1)

    LabelBottomText = Text(BottomFrame, height=10.5, width=180)
    LabelBottomText.tag_configure('style', foreground='grey', font=('calibri', 10, 'bold'))
    LabelBottomText.pack()
    fronttext = "..."
    LabelBottomText.insert(END, fronttext, 'style')

    RunProgram = Button(MiddleFrame, text="RUN PROGRAM", foreground="black", command=RUN)
    RunProgram.pack(padx=0.2, pady=0.2, side=LEFT)

    master.mainloop()
```

I designed interface my entry level program.I divide this three part.TopFrame must show turtle.Middle Frame has button which help us to start the program .Bottom Frame has debug area. I want to integrate "RunTurtle()" function into TopFrame.When the user click "RUN PROGRAM" button ,interface will open and turtle will draw pattern into TopFrame.How can I do this ? thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay, so what happens when you try running the code? How is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: When I run it , it open different window for each.I want to turtle show into topframe that's all.

Comment: In your own words, why should any of the functions in this code ever get called? How?

Comment: ı can't understand clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
def RUN():
        RunTurle()
```

should be

```
def RUN():
        RunTurtle()
```

and run the function RunGUI() its works